# Can't see logs coming from fluent forward receiver

Tags: fluentd, open-telemetry, fluent-bit

I am trying to collect application level logs using fluent-bit, I want to listen these logs on otel-collector-contrib

I am generating dummy logs for testing using the command given below
`docker run --log-driver=fluentd -t ubuntu echo "Testing a log message"`

Here, I am expecting my collector to show the logs on terminal because I have set the `loglevel` to `debug`

---

Git Repo Link : https://github.com/Bhogayata-Keval/fluentbit-demo.git

---

Did some debugging and found that issue is
`failed to parse forward mode event: unknown type of value: 1655265172 at Time at Time at Entries/0`

Also found that current timestamp is going as uint64 where expected is int64.

How to typecast timestamp to integer. Time_as_Integer property of [OUTPUT] does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you see logs on the "fluent-bit docker agent" level? Is OTEL collector running in the container? Which version of the collector you have?

Comment: @JanGaraj fluent-bit docker agent version is : 1.9.4, fluent-bit agent and otel collector both are working as a docker container. Plus, I can see the logs in my fluent-bit agent !

Comment: You didn't provide reproducible example. some files are missing, e.g. fluent-bit.conf, Dockerfile

Comment: @JanGaraj fluent-bit.conf is already mentioned in question. Plus, now I used the official docker image of otel-collector to reproduce the issue easily. Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: @JanGaraj added git repo link to reproduce the issue rapidly

Comment: what do you see in fluent-bit's log file?
I see you don't have the Match parameter in your forward output, does it make any difference if you set it?

Comment: @JoséLecaros by default it considers "Match *" if you do not specify

Comment: I found that when I use "forward" plugin as both, input and output, the timestamp goes in uint64 format, which was causing the issue --- sending data directly to localhost:8006 worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_agent_log_generate:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: https://localhost:8006
        tag: httpd.access
    command: /bin/bash -c "while sleep 2; do  echo \"Testing a log message\"; done"
```

Directly sending data to otel-endpoint like this worked !
Using forward plugin as both, input and output -- was somehow sending timestamp into uint64 format, which is not acceptable for fluentforwardreceiver